# Generating an XML document from Java objects where the structure is very different

Tags: java, xml, design-patterns, jaxb, mapping

**The Situation**

I have a complex model object graph in Java that needs to be translated back and forth into an XML document. The object graph structure of the XML document's schema is extremely different from the model's object tree. The two are interchangeable, but the translation requires lots of context-driven logic where parent/child-like relationships are used.

**The Problem**

I'm working with model objects that are well established in a older system and the XML document's schema is fairly new. Since lots of our code depends on the structure of the model objects, we don't want to restructure them. Here is a simplified example of the type of structural differences I'm dealing with:

> *Example data model tree*
>
> Item
>
> - Description
> - cost
> - ...
>
> Person
>
> - First Name
> - Last Name
> - Address
> - ...
>
> Address
>
> - Street
> - City
> - ...
>
> SaleTransaction (*this is the thing being translated)
>
> - Buyer (Person)
> - Seller (Person)
> - Sold Items[] (List)
> - Exchanged Items[] (List)
> - Location of Transaction (Address)
>
> *Example XML Document Structure*
>
> Exchange
>
> - Type
> - Parties
>
>   - party_contact_ref
>
>     - type
>     - contact_id
> - Exchange Details
>
>   - type
>   - total_amount_exchanged
> - Items
>
>   - Item
>
>     - type
>     - owning_party_contact_ref_id
>     - exchange_use_type
> - Contacts
>
>   - Contact
>
>     - id
>     - type
>
> Exchange Type: [ CASH SALE | BARTER | COMBINATION CASH AND BARTER ]
>
> Contact Type:  [ PERSON | ADDRESS ]
>
> Exchange Details Type: [ CASH EXCHANGE | BARTER EXCHANGE ]

Mapping between SaleTransaction and Exchange is possible, just not 1-1. In the example, the "buyer" in the model would be mapped to both a contact and a contact reference element in the XML document. Also, the value of the "owning_party_contact_ref_id" attribute of an "Item" element would be determined by looking at several different values in the SaleTransaction object graph.

If an object graph I'm working with needs some translation in order to be used in an XML document, my go-to tool is an XmlAdapter. In this case though, I don't see using JAXB XML adapters as a viable solution for three reasons.

1. Which XML element an object in the model graph corresponds too is data dependent. I believe all XmlAdapter to class/property mappings are fixed.
2. It doesn't seem to be possible to do a many to one, or one to many solution with XmlAdapters. MOXy has an [interesting extension](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/xmltransformation-going-beyond.html%20interesting%20extension), but again, it requires fixed mappings to properties.
3. As far as I know, XmlAdapters work with individual objects and don't have a way to get at the context of the entire graph being marshalled/unmarshalled.

**The Question**

I'm sure this type of problem is fairly common, so how do you handle it? Is there a way of handling this problem with standard tools?

**What I've come up with**

In case it's interesting, here are the possible approaches that I've come up with:

*#1*
Separate the object graph translation problem from the XML generation problem. I have a home-grown tool that assists with generating object graphs based on some context object. I could create the JAXB classes from the XML schema, then rely on this tool to generate the objects of those classes based on the context of our model object. This would work well to generate an XML document from the model object graph, but not the other way around. It also means relying on non-standard tools, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

*#2*
Go XmlAdapter crazy and modify the model classes to be able to retain translation state information (e.g. This object in the model tree was used to create this element in the XML document). This would keep the problem very close to the standard usage model for JAXB, but I think it would be a nightmare to develop, test and maintain.

*#3*
Separate the object graph problem like I would in #1, but use JDOM instead of JAXB. This would remove all of the JAXB required classes and mappings, but require another custom tool be built to manage the model object to DOM tree mappings.

I'm not super excited about any of the three solutions, but I'm most partial to #1.

Comment: You may be interested in the `@XmlPath` extension in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy).  Here is an example where the object model is quite different from the XML document:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html.

Comment: I did see the `@XmlPath` extension but I'm not sure how I manage data-driven conditional mappings with it. For example if a property of a java object can map to a subset of N possible locations in an XML document, depending on the data, how would that be done using the `@XmlPath` extension? Sorry if I'm missing something obvious!

Comment: The `@XmlPath` extension is useful for when the object model differs from the XML.  If your primary concern is having an `XmlAdapter` now about state, then you may prefer to use a stateful `XmlAdapter`: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mixing-nesting-and-references-with.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 is your best bet IMHO. Writing mapping code is tedious but you should resist the urge to be too clever. Any mapping tool you use is going to require configuration and I bet that's just as much work as writing the Java mapping code by hand. Just write lots of unit tests.

You can try Dozer for any classes that have similar named fields, it will use reflection to do the mapping. I've used this in the past, but my schema looked more similar to my domain objects, so it might not be that helpful.

To make the code more pleasant, use all the xjc plugins you can find for JAXB, such as the fluent-api and value-constructor ones.

Comment: I was a little scared that would the answer that I'd get. I'm going to hold out hope for some awesome tool or pattern that I've never heard of for a while longer. If one doesn't come in, I'll be selecting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

> If an object tree I'm working with needs some translation in order to
>   be used in an XML document, my go-to tool is an XmlAdapter. In this
>   case though, I don't see using JAXB XML adapters as a viable solution.
>   As far as I know, XmlAdapters work with individual objects and don't
>   have a way to get at the context of the entire tree being
>   marshalled/unmarshalled.

Normally an `XmlAdapter` is stateless, but you can specify an instance the `XmlAdapter` on the `Marshaller`/`Unmarshaller` that contains state.  This may be all you need.

```
YourAdapter yourAdapter = new YourAdapter();
yourAdapter.setState(someState);
marshaller.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
unmarshaller.setAdapter(yourAdapter);
```

The instance you specified on the `Marshaller`/`Unmarshaller` will be used where the corresponding class was configured:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdpater(YourAdapter.class)
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mixing-nesting-and-references-with.html

Comment: Being able to specify a specific instance of an `XmlAdapter` to be used for marshalling/unmarshalling is pretty cool, I didn't know that. However, I'm still having some trouble seeing how to handle the conditional many-to-one part of the problem. The example I threw together has a "Person" object that needs to be represented partially in 3 areas, depending on data values: `Parties/contact_ref`, `Contacts/Contact` and `Items/Item/owning_party_contact_ref`. It's this conditional part of the translation that's really driving me away from `XmlAdapter`. Maybe I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I'm not giving you a straight answer, but I can't comment yet on with my reputation, so here's my "answer".

I would definitely try [Altova XML Spy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html) and it's [Code Generation features](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-code-generation.html). I've tried it and have been incredibly useful . What I don't know if it can do is to work the other way around, but since it also has [Database connectivity](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-database.html) and some other stuff, I'm sure it won't do any harm to give it a try and play around with it.

They also have another application called [MapForce](http://www.altova.com/mapforce.html) (As in mapping databases, not GIS) which I have never tried, but from them I would expect it to be really useful.

I hope you find all of this very useful and that you can comment on this with more detail on how it helped you (or not).

Comment: I don't see how XML Spy is an improvement over the tools I already have for this problem, but MapForce is an interesting direction to go down. I was looking for more of a design pattern or Java standard tool to work with. Purchasing some proprietary software, getting it to work with our code base, and learning how to use it wouldn't be my first choice. If there isn't a code-driven solution though, MapForce does seem like a very good product.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't do more research for a more extensive answer, however I though sharing Altova products could help somehow. I used the Code Generation features in XML Spy to generate Classes from a XSD to Java and also to C#, and it worked really good. I don't know for sure, but I thought that they probably have something similar to go from a Java Object to a XSD, giving you sort of what you are looking for.

Comment: I appreciate the input! I would have never known about MapForce otherwise and that may end up being the direction we go down.

Comment: I'm glad @Terence, let me know if it worked and how, just for curiosity sake.

Answer (score 0):

If you have xsd schema it is very useful to generate pojos using tool like [castor](http://www.castor.org/). Once you have package with generated pojos you can use [dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) in order to map your "old" object model to pojos which represent xml document. Then you just transform castor generated object using Marshaller to Stream, String etc.

Comment: In a simpler case, that would work perfectly. Dozer uses reflection to do 1-1 mapping and my use case explicitly requires many-to-one mappings. That's something [not supported by dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/faq.html#mult-fields-to-single-field)

Answer (score 0):

Simplify XML document creation by structuring your code like the final document.

This code:

```java
XmlBuilder builder = XmlBuilder.create("Projects")
    .e("underscore-java").a("language", "Java").a("scm", "SVN")
        .e("Location").a("type", "URL")
            .t("https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java/")
        .up()
    .up()
    .e("JetS3t").a("language", "Java").a("scm", "CVS")
        .e("Location").a("type", "URL")
            .t("https://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html");
```

Generates the following XML document:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Projects>
    <underscore-java language="Java" scm="SVN">
        <Location type="URL">https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java/</Location>
    </underscore-java>
    <JetS3t language="Java" scm="CVS">
        <Location type="URL">https://jets3t.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html</Location>
    </JetS3t>
</Projects>
```